# Need help in Joint js workflow sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, jointjs

I've create workflow sidebar using joint js. Now when we click on any link I show some fields in sidebar. Sidebar contains some select fields also. Now I would like to add some dynamic fields according to selected option in any one select field. My current code looks like below.

```
window.workflow_sidebar = joint.ui.Workflow_sidebar.create('#workflow_sidebar-container', {
    cell: cell,
    inputs: inputs[type],
    groups: {
        general: {label: type, index: 1},
        appearance: {index: 2}
    }
});
```

Now here all inputs fields are in inputs[type] JSON. Now I need to add some more field in same inputs variable according to some condition but when I apply any condition it doesn't add those fields in existing sidebar. I need something like re-initialize workflow sidebar or inputs fields.

The code that I've tried

```
target_inputs = inputs[type];
var temp_notify_template = $('[data-attribute="notifyTemplate"]').val();

if(temp_notify_template) {
    source_inputs = {notifyParams: [{type: 'select', label: 'Type', options: [{value: 'first', content: 'first'}], group: 'notification'}]};

    final_inputs = Object.assign(target_inputs, source_inputs);
}

window.workflow_sidebar = joint.ui.Workflow_sidebar.create('#workflow_sidebar-container', {
    cell: cell,
    inputs: final_inputs,
    //inputs: inputs[type],
    groups: {
        general: {label: type, index: 1},
        appearance: {index: 2},
        notification: {index: 3}
    }
});
```

I've push some other fields in condition but when I apply condition it doesn't apply those fields on sidebar. If I apply fields without condition then it works properly with extra added field in array.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks